# How do I delete calendars in Outlook 2011 on OSX 10.7?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

How do I delete calendars in outlook 2011 on OSX 10.7

Answer (score 1):

`option+click` the calendar and select `delete "calendar name"`

Answer (score -1):

You want to select *Remove from View*.

A delegate will not have the ability to be deleted.

Comment: can you explain in a little more detail ?